# Inherit from a singleton pattern

Tags: java, oop

I've got a problem while I'm trying to inherit a class which is followed by Singleton Pattern.
Suppose there is a class, known as P, followed by Singleton Pattern and implementing an interface known as I_able.

```
abstract class P implement I_able {
    static protected I_able instance = null; 
    protected object member1;

    // abstract static I_able getInstance(); <-- this is an illegal declaration.

    abstract public void method1() ;
} // class P
```

Now, there are two class wanting to inherit from P as following.

```
class A inheritance P {
    static public I_able getInstance() {
        if ( instance == null ) 
             instance = new A() ;
        return (A) instance ;
    } // getInstance()

    override public void method1() {
        ...
    } // method1() 
} // A()

class B inheritance P {
    static public I_able getInstance() {
        if ( instance == null ) 
            instance = new B() ;
        return (B) instance ;
    } // getInstance()

    override public void method1() {
        ...
    } // method1() 
} // B()
```

The problem is why the instance in A and instance in B are the same object.
Actually, I kind of know why is that but I'm wondering how can I fix that.
A and B must be the one and only object in the program.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: Maybe this post will help you to understand the behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772977/is-it-possible-to-apply-inheritance-to-a-singleton-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is your `static I_able instance` is defined in your parent class P.

Thus, when you `getInstance`in class `A` and `B`, they would both reference to their parent's class `P`'s static variable `instance`.

I don't know a lot how you exactly want your function to execute, but one suggested edit here would be implement `Singleton` pattern in each of the children class.

```
class A inheritance P {
    static protected I_able AInstance = null; 

    static public I_able getInstance() {
        if ( AInstance == null ) 
             AInstance = new A() ;
        return (A) AInstance ;
    } // getInstance()

    override public void method1() {
        ...
    } // method1() 
} // A()

class B inheritance P {
    static protected I_able BInstance = null; 

    static public I_able getInstance() {
        if ( BInstance == null ) 
            BInstance = new B() ;
        return (B) BInstance ;
    } // getInstance()

    override public void method1() {
        ...
    } // method1() 
} // B()
```